# rewrite a jar execuable file to c#

Tags: c#, jar, url-rewriting

I've been given the task to rewrite or convert a jar program into another language like C#.
The program is like a virtual time stamper for when workers check in and out. The writer of this program made an unfinished program leaving it more or less useless if it needs an update or changing of users, cause none of the people using it is able to rewrite or edit this code. 
My problem is that I have very little to no knowledge or experience with Java programming.

My question is: Would it be easier to start from scratch or could someone with good knowledge in both Java and C# look at it and maybe point in the right direction.

MY efforts: well i tried Java Eclipse but that made me more confused than before, then i tryed a program called Java Decompiler, this is when i found out the writer is not even half done with this program, there are class files for user registration and Admin panels for editing so everything would be accessible through graphic user interface.

Heres a view of the interface (note that faces and names have been whiped due to privacy, also note that some words are in danish just ignore those. "Tids registrering" means: "time registration" and "ikke til stede" means that they are not there)

[image]

The goal is to make a program able to do:
1. Save check in/check out times and date for each user.
2. Instead of saving in a *.log it should be saved in a database.
3. Graphic interface for admin access to edit add/edit/remove users

If a Java/C# programmer wants to help we can talk about it in private about how, where and when to transfer files (again due to privacy)
If you find it too difficult or time consuming to convert i could use some help to rewrite from scratch so help from just C# programmers would also be appreciated.

---

If there is any grammatical and/or spelling errors in this post I'm sorry and apologist

Comment: If you understand everything it needs to do, just do that in C#.

Comment: What is your deadline for this? it looks like an excellent opportunity to learn some XAML + C#, and use the latest technologies and get that done in no-time. But, the problem is.. there is a learning curve...

Comment: Do you have access to the source code? Or only access to the jar / decompile?

Comment: Ryan Gates: That was my general idea but as i said I've learned C# but could use some help from a skilled c# programmer.

Comment: Java and C# are very similar. Conversion is trivial...if the program works in the first place.

Comment: HighCore: Deadline is more or less as fast as possible considering it needs to be good quality. and yea i would like to learn some more myself about these programming languages.

Comment: EtherDragon: Not at hand, i would have to get a hold of the writer who is no longer at the work place, will prove difficult but not impossible

Comment: JMS: Well it doesn't quiet work, as stated the program is not finished only partly working. There is no way to add new users or edit excising users plus a fatal problem is that only way to shut it down is with the joblist and end the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely effort to port UI from Java (either source or byte code) to C# (or any other .Net language) will be comparable or significantly higher than rewrite as frameworks are different.

For non-UI code you may be able to do direct port of most of the code either by hand or with some automated tools as languages are close enough. If original code does not have unit tests/integration tests and not written in a style you are comfortable with than cost of rewrite may be lower.

Ultimately it is *your call* if the porting effort worth it or not.

Comment: Well it is a User Interface program. I did consider starting from scratch cause as you said the effort might be too much compared to the result.